# Error Installing RabbitMQ on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

I'm trying to setup `RabbitMQ` on `Ubuntu 16.04`. I've installed `Erlang` on my machine by following this [blog](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-latest-rabbitmq-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/). I'm getting this error when I do this `sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
rabbitmq-server is already the newest version (3.8.0-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 118 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up rabbitmq-server (3.8.0-1) ...
Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript rabbitmq-server, action "start" failed.
● rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ broker
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-10-11 19:35:40 IST; 4ms ago
  Process: 20134 ExecStart=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 20134 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 11 19:35:40 developer-OptiPlex-3020 systemd[1]: Failed to start RabbitMQ broker.
dpkg: error processing package rabbitmq-server (--configure):
 installed rabbitmq-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rabbitmq-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any knowledge on how to fix this would help me. Thanks.

Comment: Did you see this? `See "systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.` Also, what is in the RabbitMQ log file, if present? Finally, the RabbitMQ team has comprehensive instructions for installing on Ubuntu, no need to read random blogs - https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html

Comment: Okay will check out the link

Comment: It's probably an issue with the service account permissions. Try running the service as root and see if it starts. Beyond this, the logs will be pretty helpful.

Comment: It was maybe a problem with dependencies, I installed using this  ```sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server -y --fix-missing
``` and it worked